# Can't find linker symbol for virtual table; cocos2d-x; iOS sdk

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, virtual

I run the game, and after some playing, debugger handles crash with description. Why virtual tables may be broken?

> warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `zombies::zpZombie' value
>   warning:   found `cocos2d::CCActionManager::addAction(cocos2d::CCAction*, cocos2d::CCNode*, bool)' instead

Compiler: Apple LLVM 3.0